# Getting rows from db and adding reserved- tag

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

what would be the right way to mark item as reserved? my current way works but i doubt it's "right" way to do it.

i've a simple query to get rows from database and then outputting them inside html tags. Here is example of my php variables:

```
$name = $row['name'];
$price = $row['price'];
$reserved = $row['reserved'];
```

and html example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name">
         $name
    </div>
    <div class="price">
         $price
    </div>
    <div class="reserved">
         $reserved
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if a item is reserved, then i just add text to reserved- field in database.

I hide all "reserved" divs in css. Then i'm using jquery to loop through all "reserved" items. I check if that div has text, if it has, then i show it and after that i clear it.

```
$(".reserved").each(function(index) {

 if($(this).is(":empty")) {

    $(this).hide();

 }

$(this).empty();

});
```

After that all items which had text in "reserved" field in database will have different layout. As they're supposed to have. It works but i don't think this is the right way.. can someone lead me to the right way? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to specify what sort of behavior you want? Right now i seem unclear to me!

Comment: Hi, i want exactly the same behaviour. Expect, i feel like i'm doing that thing wrong. How are these kind of things usually done? I mean, is there a more efficient way of doing this or do you consider this as a good practise?